Python Add datetime column in dataframe from an existing column
I have data in csv file as below
v,vw,o,c,h,l,t,n
18043.0,374.411,374.69,374.99,374.99,373.8,1656662400000,157
12003.0,375.6296,375.15,375.84,375.9,374.95,1656663300000,98
18426.0,376.0636,375.98,376.02,376.29,375.63,1656664200000,88
4700.0,376.0772,375.88,376.11,376.34,375.85,1656665100000,43
27969.0,376.5703,376.11,376.56,376.92,375.82,1656666000000,135
17922.0,376.7123,376.69,376.48,376.89,376.46,1656666900000,95
11805.0,376.5813,376.6,376.38,376.71,376.38,1656667800000,74
19888.0,376.9877,376.28,377.11,377.2,376.28,1656668700000,100
7853.0,376.7016,377.25,376.66,377.25,376.48,1656669600000,67
36560.0,377.3454,376.69,377.05,377.8,376.69,1656670500000,175
10862.0,376.354,376.74,376.06,376.74,376.06,1656671400000,92
14740.0,375.8719,376.09,375.74,376.09,375.71,1656672300000,126
78885.0,375.9584,375.88,375.901,376.14,375.71,1656673200000,628
43363.0,376.0552,375.8,376.31,376.4,375.68,1656674100000,277
...

where column t is having UTC unix timestamp in miliseconds (1/1000).  I would like to add a column to the dataframe with timestamp in EST.  Is there a way to achieve the same without going through each row?  I tried few things but I am getting error similar to

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>


Convert the column to datetime, then convert the timezone from UTC to EST:
df["t"] = pd.to_datetime(df["t"], unit="ms")
df["t"] = df["t"].dt.tz_localize("UTC").dt.tz_convert("US/Eastern")

          v        vw       o        c       h       l                         t    n
0   18043.0  374.4110  374.69  374.990  374.99  373.80 2022-07-01 04:00:00-04:00  157
1   12003.0  375.6296  375.15  375.840  375.90  374.95 2022-07-01 04:15:00-04:00   98
2   18426.0  376.0636  375.98  376.020  376.29  375.63 2022-07-01 04:30:00-04:00   88
3    4700.0  376.0772  375.88  376.110  376.34  375.85 2022-07-01 04:45:00-04:00   43
4   27969.0  376.5703  376.11  376.560  376.92  375.82 2022-07-01 05:00:00-04:00  135
5   17922.0  376.7123  376.69  376.480  376.89  376.46 2022-07-01 05:15:00-04:00   95
6   11805.0  376.5813  376.60  376.380  376.71  376.38 2022-07-01 05:30:00-04:00   74
7   19888.0  376.9877  376.28  377.110  377.20  376.28 2022-07-01 05:45:00-04:00  100
8    7853.0  376.7016  377.25  376.660  377.25  376.48 2022-07-01 06:00:00-04:00   67
9   36560.0  377.3454  376.69  377.050  377.80  376.69 2022-07-01 06:15:00-04:00  175
10  10862.0  376.3540  376.74  376.060  376.74  376.06 2022-07-01 06:30:00-04:00   92
11  14740.0  375.8719  376.09  375.740  376.09  375.71 2022-07-01 06:45:00-04:00  126
12  78885.0  375.9584  375.88  375.901  376.14  375.71 2022-07-01 07:00:00-04:00  628
13  43363.0  376.0552  375.80  376.310  376.40  375.68 2022-07-01 07:15:00-04:00  277

